# What happens when the type parameter is not defined when constructing a TreeSet in java?

Tags: java, collections, set

What is the expected result when the type parameter is not defined such as in the below code-
Code Segment 1:

```
java.util.Set set = new java.util.TreeSet();
set.add(2);
```

Code Segment 2:

```
java.util.Set set = new java.util.TreeSet();
set.add("2");
```

Code segment 1 and 2 run fine.
Code Segment 3:

```
java.util.Set set = new java.util.TreeSet();
set.add("2");
set.add(3);
```

Code Segment 4:

```
java.util.Set set = new java.util.TreeSet();
set.add(2);
set.add("3");
```

Code segment 3 and 4 fail with following errors respectively:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
```

So does java take up the first addition as the default type for the set?
Also, the error seems to be weird, shouldn't it be Integer to String for Code Segment 3 and String to Integer for Code Segment 4?

Additionally, what happens for other collections if type parameter is not defined?

Comment: To your last question, it's because the `TreeSet` is trying to compare the newly inserted value to the existing values in the set using `compareTo`.

Comment: Alright got the point, thank you @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-